# Puppet -> puppetserver ca list --all --> 'plus' sign

Tags: puppet

currently i'm playing with puppet in my private lab.
I've installed puppetserver and agent.
Everything looks good but could you tell me please why don't see this plus sign next to the certificates?

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnVTx.jpg)
[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzwM4.png)

Comment: Where do you expect to see plus signs, and why?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.
I was hoping that someone would write back to me :)
Basically, following the udemy tutorial (I have similar situation at work). The fact that the certificate is signed by the master is marked with a plus on the left side.
In the tutorial there is version 5 of openpuppet. Ive installed versions 6 and 7 in home environment and on aws (other commands, e.g. 'puppetserver ca sign' instead of 'puppet cert sign'). The message indicates that the certificates are signed but this plus is not there (and it should be according to the instructor on Udemy).
Regards

Comment: Ive attached a 2 screen to the post

Answer (score 1):

> could you tell me please why don't see this plus sign next to the certificates?

Because recent versions of `puppetserver ca` don't do that.

Without the `--all` option, `puppetserer ca` lists only unfulfilled certificate-signing requests, which earlier versions of the CA face would not have marked with a '+' anyway.  Most of the time, there should be very few of these.  In fact, there should be *none* most of the time unless something is wrong or the site is very busy with new node registrations.

On the other hand, `puppetserver ca --all` lists both unfulfilled CSRs and signed certs, but instead of distinguishing them by presence or absence of a flag character, it separates these into separate groups, each led by a descriptive heading.  Since the signed certs will normally be most, and often all, of the entries, marking them with a flag character would be mostly noise.

Comment: okay, that is to sum up:
in newer versions of puppet, the + flag is not needed for these certificates. And in the first case in the attached picture, I understand that they are grouped as signed and everything is ok. Got that right?

Comment: That's right, @ban4n.

Comment: OK. thanks for your help:) Regards